# Django template - multiple plural phrases in one sentence

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, translation

In my project there's a sentence need to be translated. Here it is:

```
We provide {{book_count}} book(s), {{game_account}} game(s) and {{album_account}} music album(s) for you.
```

We need to handle the singular and plural form for it, and it has 3 counters here. I find it's not easy to use django i18n tag for it.

For now I extract the phrases out as model values, handle them one by one first, then pass to the sentence. Like this:

```
{%blocktrans with books=book_text games=game_text albums=album_text %}We provide {{books}}, {{games}} and {{albums}} for you.{%endblocktrans%}
```

This seems no good for me. Maybe there's a better way to deal with this, or blockstrans can have some kind of nested syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pluralize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize) filter to convert text to its plural form based on some variable.